# How can I use a sql reserved keyword in the name of a property in an entity framework data context?

Tags: c#, .net, poco, code-first, entity-framework-4.3

The following code throws the exception "*EntitySqlException: 'Group' is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias, unless it is escaped. Near line 1, column 11*".

My question is firstly why is there any relation between the name of the collection I choose on my data context and, seeminlgy the sql query that is generated?

And secondly, is there anything I can do, besides renaming the property on my context, to resolve it (I know the name is stupid, there are  reasons why I cannot change the name, much as I would like to, that I won't go into here)?

Is there something I can do with the modelBuilder perhaps?

```
public class GroupEntity
{
    public int GroupEntityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        Group = Set<GroupEntity>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupEntity>().ToTable("GroupEntities");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<GroupEntity> Group { get; private set; }
}

//...
using (var ctx = new MyContext("valid connection string"))
{
    var e = ctx.Group.Count(a => a.GroupEntityId % 2 == 0);
    // Exception thrown here
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: You have already realised that the name is stupid, so +1 there :) Group is both a generic term (instead of relating to the data it holds) and a reserved word for LINQ. Have you tried the full `var e = FROM a in ctx.Group` LINQ syntax instead to see if it sneaks through? If you *could* explain why you cannot rename it that might help?

Comment: Thanks, yes, the reasons why I cannot change the name are not technical so I don't think they would help here.  Incidentally, there are other things I could have called it which would result in the same exception, for example "Using, As, Select" so I am interested just to know if it is possible not to rename the property before I use the fact that it is not as the reason to change it (along with the other reasons you mentioned), if you see what I mean :-)

Comment: To repeat: Have you tried the full `var e = FROM a in ctx.Group` LINQ syntax instead to see if it sneaks through? In theory it creates the same IL under the hood, but worth a quick try.

Comment: If EF throws an error here, my opinion is that this is a bug in EF. Any ORM should be providing correct escaping for object/column names, which usually means lots of `[` / `]` in the TSQL (not sure about ESQL, I'm less fluent in that dialect; edit - I have confirmed that `[` / `]` would indeed fix this). IMO this should just work; your expectation is reasonable.

Comment: @HiTechMagic I disagree - the naming here is up to the application; in LINQ, `group` is a *contextual* keyword, not a *reserved* keyword, so should never cause a problem, plus C# has the `@` escape even for that. Frankly, this is an EF bug in my opinion.

Comment: @HiTech Magic sorry, no, doing that does not mean that it sneaks through

Comment: @Marc thanks, I thought it was a bug in EF too (albeit a rare one because you can make various cases around why you shouldn't call your property that even though, from a purest point of view it feels like it should just work and the entity framework should just handle it)

Comment: @HiTechMagic what has L2S got to do with this? In every L2S case I've seen, it correctly uses `[`/`]`. Are you saying that ugly SQL is a bug? EF has the trump on that **every** day of the week.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Incorrect comment removed... I will stop trying to agree with you now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in EF 4.3.1 and EF 5.0 beta1. Please use NuGet to update the EntityFramework package to the latest version. For example, in the Package Manager Console, run:

```
Update-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I updated to 4.3.1 (I was on 4.3) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

So after a while of looking at this I have concluded that the answer to my question is that it is not possible.

This is not a massive deal, since I can rename the property, but I think it is something that should "just work" and so I raised an MS connect issue for it that can be found here: [Using a sql reserved keyword as the name of a collection on a DbContext causes an exception](https://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/730209/using-a-sql-reserved-keyword-as-the-name-of-a-collection-on-a-dbcontext-causes-an-exception).  If this gets resolved or rejected because it is actually possible I will update this answer.

---

**UPDATE:** This is now resolved. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9672366/1158174).

Answer (score 0):

You can always make it plural, like Groups to make it a "non-reserved" word.

Comment: thanks, yes, my question was how I can get around it without changing the name of the property though and I think the actual answer is "you can't - it is a bug in entity framework"